# No tests executed - Acceptance test Codeception

Tags: codeception

I get the same error when I try to run an acceptance test with codeception.

```
C:\Users\DEFAULT.DESKTOP-RJ3G5I9\vendor\bin>codecept run acceptance GoogleTest.php
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v4.1.6
Powered by PHPUnit 9.2.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed:

class TestGoogle
{
    public function testGoogle(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('https://www.google.com');
                $I->see('Google');
    }
}
Acceptance Tests (0) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
No tests executed!

Anybody has any idea on that? Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed opening PHP tag at the top of GoogleTest.php file.

Also class name must have suffix maching its format.
You are using Cest format here so the class and the file must be named GoogleCest and GoogleCest.php accordingly.